# Selenium IE11 file download - Non Robot framework solution

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer-11

I'm looking for a solution in a Java Selenium test to interact with the IE11 download file dialog without needing to use Robot framework. Our team needs to be able to run a large number of tests unattended across multiple remote VMs. Using Robot framework requires us to always keep the RDP window opened and focused so the precise Robot framework clicking can happen without interruptions. It is not a viable solution.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Code trials please....

Comment: Selenium web driver does not have the capability to automate the save file dialog of the IE browser. To perform this task, you need to use any third-party library that can automate those save file dialog. So if you want to perform this task only using the Selenium web driver then it is not possible.